# Multiple default values specified for column "uid" of table in Django 1.8

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I am creating a `Django Application`, and my `models.py` is :

```
class Registration(models.Model):
    uid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, default=0)
    uname = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    upassword = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    uphone = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    uhid = models.ForeignKey('Hood', blank=False, null=False, default='ABC')
    uemail = models.EmailField(blank=False, null=False, default='abc402@nyu.edu')
    uintro = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    uphoto = models.ImageField(upload_to='', blank=False, null=False, default='static/img/natural_join_is_inner_join.png')
    uhood = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    uaddress = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='ABC')
    # django automatically uses the media root which you have declared in your settings, define that to `upload_to`

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.uname
```

I then run the following commands:

`python manage.py makemigrations`

`python manage.py migrate`

But it is showing me an error:

> multiple default values specified for column "uid" of table
>   "registration_registration"

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue? The other links on stack overflow are not of much help!

When I removed id `uid` field then Django is showing me:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'id' to registration without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
```

The issue is why I should provide a default value for `id` which django automatically creates?

UPDATE: I have deleted the migration folder, so I was resolve the above issue but now I am getting an error:

> "Error creating new content types. Please make sure contenttypes "
>   RuntimeError: Error creating new content types. Please make sure
>   contenttypes is migrated before trying to migrate apps individually.

Comment: Obviously something got messed up with your migrations. Try to delete the migrations folder again and run migrate once before makemigrations.

Comment: I don't have migration folder now. I am planning to delete the database and create a new one? Do you think thats a good idea!

Comment: Well it really depends on the data in it... If it is only a new dev db with nothing in it I would delete it. It is hard to tell what exactly happened without knowing many other details.

Answer (score 4):

You should not have defined a `default` value for `uid` in the first place. It's an AutoField, it gets an auto-incremented value from the database.

Comment: My error is different now if you see last few lines.